# Json array i want to display the names and id

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
```

How to Parse this i am getting an error and i am really new here this is my first question

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io?share=CCVxYymczm7gdgZ5vCAI

Comment: How do you want the output to be exactly? Do you need a new array with objects containing only the name and the id? Please be more specific of what you are trying to do with this json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure if your json data is just a variable or external url calling through api. Also i have shortened the array.
if its normal variable. you can use foreach.

```js
    let jsonVar = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Leanne Graham", "username": "Bret", "email": "Sincere@april.biz", "address": { "street": "Kulas Light", "suite": "Apt. 556", "city": "Gwenborough", "zipcode": "92998-3874", "geo": { "lat": "-37.3159", "lng": "81.1496" } }, "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442", "website": "hildegard.org", "company": { "name": "Romaguera-Crona", "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", "bs": "harness real-time e-markets" } }, { "id": 2, "name": "Ervin Howell", "username": "Antonette", "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv", "address": { "street": "Victor Plains", "suite": "Suite 879", "city": "Wisokyburgh", "zipcode": "90566-7771", "geo": { "lat": "-43.9509", "lng": "-34.4618" } }, "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125", "website": "anastasia.net", "company": { "name": "Deckow-Crist", "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency", "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains" } } ];

    jsonVar.forEach((item) => {
       document.querySelector("#json-data").innerHTML += `<h1>${item.name}</h1> <h2>${item.id}</h2> <hr>`;
    });
```

```html
<div id="json-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mylist = [ { "id": 1, "name": "Leanne Graham", "username": "Bret", "email": "Sincere@april.biz", "address": { "street": "Kulas Light", "suite": "Apt. 556", "city": "Gwenborough", "zipcode": "92998-3874", "geo": { "lat": "-37.3159", "lng": "81.1496" } }, "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442", "website": "hildegard.org", "company": { "name": "Romaguera-Crona", "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", "bs": "harness real-time e-markets" } }, { "id": 2, "name": "Ervin Howell", "username": "Antonette", "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv", "address": { "street": "Victor Plains", "suite": "Suite 879", "city": "Wisokyburgh", "zipcode": "90566-7771", "geo": { "lat": "-43.9509", "lng": "-34.4618" } }, "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125", "website": "anastasia.net", "company": { "name": "Deckow-Crist", "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency", "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains" } }, { "id": 3, "name": "Clementine Bauch", "username": "Samantha", "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net", "address": { "street": "Douglas Extension", "suite": "Suite 847", "city": "McKenziehaven", "zipcode": "59590-4157", "geo": { "lat": "-68.6102", "lng": "-47.0653" } }, "phone": "1-463-123-4447", "website": "ramiro.info", "company": { "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson", "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface", "bs": "e-enable strategic applications" } }, { "id": 4, "name": "Patricia Lebsack", "username": "Karianne", "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org", "address": { "street": "Hoeger Mall", "suite": "Apt. 692", "city": "South Elvis", "zipcode": "53919-4257", "geo": { "lat": "29.4572", "lng": "-164.2990" } }, "phone": "493-170-9623 x156", "website": "kale.biz", "company": { "name": "Robel-Corkery", "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity", "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services" } }, { "id": 5, "name": "Chelsey Dietrich", "username": "Kamren", "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca", "address": { "street": "Skiles Walks", "suite": "Suite 351", "city": "Roscoeview", "zipcode": "33263", "geo": { "lat": "-31.8129", "lng": "62.5342" } }, "phone": "(254)954-1289", "website": "demarco.info", "company": { "name": "Keebler LLC", "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution", "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems" } }, { "id": 6, "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist", "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery", "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info", "address": { "street": "Norberto Crossing", "suite": "Apt. 950", "city": "South Christy", "zipcode": "23505-1337", "geo": { "lat": "-71.4197", "lng": "71.7478" } }, "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430", "website": "ola.org", "company": { "name": "Considine-Lockman", "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface", "bs": "e-enable innovative applications" } }, { "id": 7, "name": "Kurtis Weissnat", "username": "Elwyn.Skiles", "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz", "address": { "street": "Rex Trail", "suite": "Suite 280", "city": "Howemouth", "zipcode": "58804-1099", "geo": { "lat": "24.8918", "lng": "21.8984" } }, "phone": "210.067.6132", "website": "elvis.io", "company": { "name": "Johns Group", "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force", "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers" } }, { "id": 8, "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V", "username": "Maxime_Nienow", "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me", "address": { "street": "Ellsworth Summit", "suite": "Suite 729", "city": "Aliyaview", "zipcode": "45169", "geo": { "lat": "-14.3990", "lng": "-120.7677" } }, "phone": "586.493.6943 x140", "website": "jacynthe.com", "company": { "name": "Abernathy Group", "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept", "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers" } }, { "id": 9, "name": "Glenna Reichert", "username": "Delphine", "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io", "address": { "street": "Dayna Park", "suite": "Suite 449", "city": "Bartholomebury", "zipcode": "76495-3109", "geo": { "lat": "24.6463", "lng": "-168.8889" } }, "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206", "website": "conrad.com", "company": { "name": "Yost and Sons", "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project", "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies" } }, { "id": 10, "name": "Clementina DuBuque", "username": "Moriah.Stanton", "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz", "address": { "street": "Kattie Turnpike", "suite": "Suite 198", "city": "Lebsackbury", "zipcode": "31428-2261", "geo": { "lat": "-38.2386", "lng": "57.2232" } }, "phone": "024-648-3804", "website": "ambrose.net", "company": { "name": "Hoeger LLC", "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force", "bs": "target end-to-end models" } } ];

document.body.innerHTML += `<div><ul id="listView"></ul></div>`;

mylist.forEach((item) => { 
document.querySelector("#listView").innerHTML += `<ul>${item.id} - ${item.name}`;
console.log(item.id, item.name) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your json is saved as a string in the variable 'json', then you can use something like this:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);
let result = [];
parsed.forEach((e) => {
    result.push({id: e['id'], name: e['name']});
});
```

Hope this helps you get started, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can map it with `destructing` the object. Like this:

```js
var data=[ { "id": 1, "name": "Leanne Graham", "username": "Bret", "email": "Sincere@april.biz", "address": { "street": "Kulas Light", "suite": "Apt. 556", "city": "Gwenborough", "zipcode": "92998-3874", "geo": { "lat": "-37.3159", "lng": "81.1496" } }, "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442", "website": "hildegard.org", "company": { "name": "Romaguera-Crona", "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net", "bs": "harness real-time e-markets" } }, { "id": 2, "name": "Ervin Howell", "username": "Antonette", "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv", "address": { "street": "Victor Plains", "suite": "Suite 879", "city": "Wisokyburgh", "zipcode": "90566-7771", "geo": { "lat": "-43.9509", "lng": "-34.4618" } }, "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125", "website": "anastasia.net", "company": { "name": "Deckow-Crist", "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency", "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains" } }];

var result = data.map(({id,name})=>({id, name}));

console.log(result);
```